# jQuery UI Draggable + css Line-Height issue

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have the 'Line-height' attribute set to .8 which affects any text within `<div id="bigtextContainer">`.

My problem is that the div is draggable from outside of its [top + bottom] bounds. I have the div background set to 'red' and you can see the 'move' cursor appears before you reach the [top + bottom] div area. Draggable seems to be using the original line-height, as when use remove the line-height the div is draggable within its correct bounds.

Here is my example : [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niczoom/6BRkE/13/)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `overflow:hidden;` on `#bigtextContainer`